# mysql stored procedure issue: insert runs first and always whatever If condition I put

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

Need quick help, in below SQL insert is fired first then other select queries are fired. insert statement is executed whatever If condition I put.
I am testing this in phpMyAdmin.
I tried to also convert the insert statement in to separate stored procedure but then also result is same.
Thanks in Advance..

```
    DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS get_top$$
CREATE PROCEDURE get_top(
IN tolerance INT,
IN cred INT,
IN cgreen INT,
IN cblue INT,
IN userID INT,
IN mapID BIGINT
)

BEGIN
DECLARE topList VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE top1 VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE top2 VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE top3 VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE get_result VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE dev_notes VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL;

SET sql_mode = 'NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION';

SELECT CONCAT(top_1, ';', top_2, ';', top_3) INTO topList
FROM Tops
WHERE red = cred AND green = cgreen AND  blue = cblue
ORDER BY top_ID asc
LIMIT 0 , 1 ;

SELECT topList,cred,cgreen,cblue;

IF topList IS NULL THEN BEGIN
    SELECT  top_1, top_2, top_3 
    INTO top1, top2, top3
    FROM Tops 
    WHERE top_1>0
    LIMIT 0 , 1 ;

    SELECT "in IF",top1,CHAR_LENGTH(top1);

    IF (top1 IS NULL) THEN 
        SET  get_result:= 'None';
    ELSE
        SET  get_result:= 'Nearest';
    END IF;

    SET topList=top1+ ','+ top2+ ','+ top3;

    SET dev_notes='result:'+get_result+' mapID:'+mapID+' User ID:'+userID+' date/time:'+NOW();
    SELECT topList,get_result;

    INSERT INTO Tops (red,green,blue,top_1,top_2,top_3,notes) VALUES (cred,cgreen,cblue,top1,top2,top3,dev_notes);
END;
ELSE BEGIN
    SET  get_result:= 'Exact';
    SELECT "in else",topList,get_result,dev_notes;
END; END IF;

IF CHAR_LENGTH(mapID)>0 THEN
    UPDATE Map SET toponym=toponymList, toponym_conf=get_result WHERE map_ID=mapID;
END IF;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: This code does not compile , and are you sure that you are using mysql and not sql server?

Comment: I would suspect at least one of top_1,top_2 and top_3 returns null.

Comment: Salmon, Thanks for your quick response. please review the code now it should compile. I am using MySQL and need to use that only. I am testing the code using myphpAdmin.

Comment: + is not a mysql string concatenation function - you should look at the statements where you use + and change them if need be.

Comment: You are not passing values for top_1,top_2 or top_3 into the procedure so if this is the only route that inserts occur to Tops then top_1,_top_2 and top_3 will always be null therefor toplist will always be null and the logic will always fall into the IF topList IS NULL THEN condition.

Comment: @P.Salmon Moving from + to CONCAT() doesn't help, While in your 2nd comment topList is getting value first on run of select query that uses INTO, if will only be NULL if select don’t find any record. Again top1, top2, top3 also gets values from select using INTO top1, top2, top3. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @P.Salmon I updated default values for all the declared variables but that too doesn’t help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have amended you code to write debug messages to a table so that I can illustrate what is happening.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS get_top$$
CREATE PROCEDURE get_top(
IN tolerance INT,
IN cred INT,
IN cgreen INT,
IN cblue INT,
IN userID INT,
IN mapID BIGINT
)

BEGIN
DECLARE topList VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL;
declare topsid int;
DECLARE top1 VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT null;
DECLARE top2 VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT null;
DECLARE top3 VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT null;
DECLARE get_result VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE dev_notes VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL;

SET sql_mode = 'NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION';

SELECT top_id,CONCAT(top_1, ';', top_2, ';', top_3) INTO topsid,topList
FROM Tops
WHERE red = cred AND green = cgreen AND  blue = cblue
ORDER BY top_ID asc
LIMIT 0 , 1 ;

insert into debug_table (msg) values (concat('Start topsid:', coalesce(topsid,'not found'),' toplist:',coalesce(topList,'null'),' cred:',cred,' cgreen:',cgreen,' cblue:',cblue));

IF topList IS NULL THEN 
BEGIN
    SELECT  top_1, top_2, top_3 
    INTO top1, top2, top3
    FROM Tops 
    WHERE top_1>0
    LIMIT 0 , 1 ;

    insert into debug_table (msg) values (concat("in IF",' top1:',coalesce(top1,'null'),' len top1:',if(top1 is not null,CHAR_LENGTH(top1),0)));

    IF (top1 IS NULL) THEN 
        SET  get_result:= 'None';
    ELSE
        SET  get_result:= 'Nearest';
    END IF;

    SET topList=top1+ ','+ top2+ ','+ top3;

    #SET dev_notes='result:'+get_result+' mapID:'+mapID+' User ID:'+userID+' date/time:'+NOW();
    SET dev_notes=CONCAT('result:',get_result,' mapID:',mapID,' User ID:',userID,' date/time:',NOW());

     insert into debug_table (msg) values (concat('about to insert toplist:',coalesce(topList,'null'),' get_result:',get_result,' dev_notes:',DEV_NOTES));

    INSERT INTO Tops (red,green,blue,top_1,top_2,top_3,notes) VALUES (cred,cgreen,cblue,top1,top2,top3,dev_notes);
END;
ELSE BEGIN
    SET  get_result:= 'Exact';
   insert into debug_table (msg) values (concat(' in else toplist:',coalesce(topList,'null'),' get_result:',get_result,' dev_notes:',DEV_NOTES));
END; 
END IF;
#SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(MAPID);
#IF CHAR_LENGTH(mapID)>0 THEN
#    UPDATE Map SET toponym=toponymList, toponym_conf=get_result WHERE map_ID=mapID;
#END IF;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

So if tops looks something like this

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TOPS;
CREATE TABLE TOPS(TOP_ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
red INT,green INT,blue INT,top_1 varchar(4),top_2 varchar(4),top_3 varchar(4),notes VARCHAR(100));
```

And I do this

```
ariaDB [sandbox]> TRUNCATE TABLE TOPS;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.16 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> truncate table debug_table;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.24 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> CALL GET_TOP(1,1,1,1,'1','1');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.17 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from tops;
+--------+------+-------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| TOP_ID | red  | green | blue | top_1 | top_2 | top_3 | notes                                                       |
+--------+------+-------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|      1 |    1 |     1 |    1 | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | result:None mapID:1 User ID:1 date/time:2017-07-20 09:45:00 |
+--------+------+-------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> CALL GET_TOP(1,1,1,1,'1','1');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.10 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> SELECT * FROM debug_table;
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | msg                                                                                                                |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | Start topsid:not found toplist:null cred:1 cgreen:1 cblue:1                                                        |
|  2 | in IF top1:null len top1:0                                                                                         |
|  3 | about to insert toplist:null get_result:None dev_notes:result:None mapID:1 User ID:1 date/time:2017-07-20 09:45:00 |
|  4 | Start topsid:1 toplist:null cred:1 cgreen:1 cblue:1                                                                |
|  5 | in IF top1:null len top1:0                                                                                         |
|  6 | about to insert toplist:null get_result:None dev_notes:result:None mapID:1 User ID:1 date/time:2017-07-20 09:45:00 |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I would expect on the first call that no record will be found in tops and topslist will be null and this is proved by the first three records in the debug_table. On the second call a record is found in tops but since top_1,top_2 and top_3 are null then topslist is again null. The select in the if "fails" because there are no tops_1 records with a value > 0 so another record is inserted with null values to tops this is traceable in the debug_table records 4 -6.  BTW checking a varchar field for a value > 0 is not a good idea.

Comment: Hi @P.Salmon I update my sql but on one run it runs twice first goes in ELSE & then again goes in IF. debug_table looks (below output is only of one run). What else could I be missing here
1. Start topsid:not found toplist:null cred:235 cgreen:235 cblue:236
2. in ELSE top1:building len toponym1:8
3. about to insert topList:building,generic,3D get_result:Nearest dev_notes:result:Nearest  mapID:23847211122707 User ID:0 date/time:2017-07-21 07:12:56
4. Start topsid:305 toplist:building;generic;3D cred:235 cgreen:235 cblue:236
5.  in if get_toponym:building;generic;3D get_result:Exact

Comment: I found out the issue with it running twice. Not sure why but it was due to "SELECT topList,get_result;" once I removed the line, its working fine. Thanks a lot for your response & time. I very much appreciate it.